# Spring AutoPopulatingList max size?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem with the Spring AutoPopulatingList. My use case is the following : manage the list of users that can access an application.

On the GUI side, I use an autocomplete field to search and add users to a table on the right. Users can also be removed from the table.
When the GUI user submits, the GUI dynamically builds a form with fields for the users : selectedUsers[1], ..., selectedUsers[N].

My problem is that the AutoPopulatingList in my "backing" bean seems to grow only to 256 items, and then stops. So I get the following error :

[myapp.web.controller.admin.form.ApplicationForm]: Invalid list index in property path 'selectedUsers[256]'; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 256, Size: 256

Do you know if there is the actual limit ? If it is, is there a way to raise it ?
If not, can you think of a workaround for this problem ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, so I dug a little more into Spring's internals and found that by default, 256 is the limit.

The limit is given by the BeanWrapperImpl#autoGrowCollectionLimit attribute. Spring's WebDataBinder default configuration sets this to 256.

The proper way to raise this limit is to define a @InitBinder annotated method in your controller :

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(1024);
}
```

and then everything works as expected.

I did not try to find a way to modify this limit globally.

HTH

Comment: You could put this in a class annotated with @ControllerAdvice to configure it for all of your controllers.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html

Comment: Worst part about this is the cryptic error messages "Index out of bounds".

Answer (score 3):

In Java, `List` are 0-indexed. The first index is then `selectedUsers[0]` and the last one is `selectedUsers[255]` if the list contains 256 elements.

It seems that you are trying to access `selectedUsers[256]` (the 257th element) while the list only contains 256 elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes the problem is a size problem. The list is auto populated by Spring from the HTTP request. My problem is that there is more than 256 elements to map on that list. And I do not see where Spring specifies this limit of 256, or where I can raise it.

Answer (score 0):

After some reading, looks like there is a "LazyList" interface that you can use to tell Spring "hey this list can be expanded" using the "getBlocks()" method.

See a full example here:
http://mattfleming.com/node/134

I can't seem to get it to work in my own project though.  I think some sort of @Bean interface might be in order?