# Using a List in a Spring 3 form backing object seems dangerous

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, data-binding

It appears that when a `List` is used in a Spring 3 form backing object, it will be filled with entries up to the index passed in the form post. That could result in a very large `List` and a lot of objects if a malicious user were to pass in a large `int` value for the index.

I tried an experiment with the following class for the form backing object:

```
public class Form
{
    private List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getValues()
    {
        return this.values;
    }
}
```

When the following input was posted:

```
<input type="text" name="form.values[10]" value="HaHa" />
```

the resulting `List` contained 11 entries. The first ten were `null`, while the entry at index 10 contained the string "HaHa".

Imagine what would happen if the following input were posted instead:

```
<input type="text" name="form.values[12147483647]" value="HaHa" />
```

The resulting `List` would take up quite a bit of memory.

It seems to be even worse if it is a `List` of beans instead of strings. Spring appears to fill the list with beans, rather than `null` values.

Is there a way to avoid this?

I know I could use a `Map` instead of a `List` and later create a `List` using the entries in the `Map`, but is there another way?

Note: I am using Spring 3.1.0.

Comment: could you not use an AutoPopulatingList? It has a default max size of 256

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan - Thanks. That looks like a possibility. I had read about `AutoPopulatingList` before, but the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/util/AutoPopulatingList.html) does not mention anything about a max size. But I see it is mentioned in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20946573/859640). It seems like that should be documented, and it would be more convenient if the max size could be set via the constructor.